# how to handle different monitor aspect ratio problem?

Tags: html, css, responsive

I have the following web page:

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
        <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            .lower,
            .upper {
                padding:0px;
                margin:0px;
                border: 1px solid black;
                position:relative;
            }
            .upperToolbar{
                border: 1px solid black;
                z-index:1;
                position:absolute;
                float:left;
                width:100%;

                bottom:0;
                text-align:center;
                display:flex;
                justify-content:center;
            }
            .wrapper {
              display: grid;
              padding:5px;
              margin:5px;
              grid-gap: 5px;
              grid-template-columns: 1fr;
              grid-template-rows: 6.5fr 3.5fr;
              border: 1px solid black;
            }
            /* Extra small devices (phones, 600px and down) */
            @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
                body {
                    background-color: red;
                }
            }

            /* Small devices (portrait tablets and large phones, 600px and up) */
            @media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
                body {
                    background-color: green;
                }               
            }

            /* Medium devices (landscape tablets, 768px and up) */
            @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
                body {
                    background-color: blue;
                }
            }

            /* Large devices (laptops/desktops, 992px and up) */
            @media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
                body {
                    background-color: magenta;
                }
            }

            /* Extra large devices (large laptops and desktops, 1200px and up) */
            @media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
                body {
                    background-color: Beige;
                }
            }

            html,body {
                height:100%;
                width:100%;
                padding:0px;
                margin:0px;
                display: grid;
                grid-template-columns: 1fr;
                grid-template-rows: 1fr;
            }
            video{
                float:left;
                height:100%;
                width:100%;
                object-fit:cover;
                z-index:0;
                position:absolute;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="upper">
                <div class="upperToolbar">
                    <picture>
                        <source media="(max-width: 600px)" srcset="img/share_video_48.png">
                        <source media="(min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 767px)" srcset="img/share_video_64.png">
                        <source media="(min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px)" srcset="img/share_video_128.png">
                        <source media="(min-width: 991px)" srcset="img/share_video_64.png">
                        <img src="img/share_video_48.png">
                    </picture>
                    <picture>
                        <source media="(max-width: 600px)" srcset="img/share_audio_48.png">
                        <source media="(min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 767px)" srcset="img/share_audio_64.png">
                        <source media="(min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px)" srcset="img/share_audio_128.png">
                        <source media="(min-width: 991px)" srcset="img/share_audio_64.png">
                        <img src="img/share_video_48.png">
                    </picture>                  
                </div>
                <video id="selfView"></video>
            </div>
            <div class="lower">
                L
            </div>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have 2 images on this web page, I am using the monitor width to determine which images will be used.

To test the layout, I got 2 mobile phones(named mobile A and mobile B) to browse this web.
The mobile A screen is narrower and shorter than that of mobile B, whereas
my PC monitor is wider than the mobile B.

In mobile A, I use 48 X 48-pixel images to act as the buttons on mobile A, it looks fine.

Mobile B has a wider and higher screen than that of mobile A.

Unfortunately, although the mobile B screen is narrower than PC monitor, if I use 96 X 96-pixel images to act as the buttons on mobile B, I found it is too small;

So, I need to use 128 X 128-pixel images to act as the buttons in mobile B.

Although the PC monitor is wider than that of mobile B, if I use 128 x 128-pixel images to act as buttons on the PC monitor, I found it is too large.

Finally, I found that I use 64 x 64-pixel images to act as buttons on the PC monitor, it looks fine.

Why the mobile B screen can show the 128 X 128-pixel image normally?
And why the PC monitor shows the 128 X 128-pixel image on a very large scale, even it has a wider screen?

As I know the wider monitor, I need to use bigger images, however, in this case, it shows me that is not always true.

Is there any best practice to handle this issue?

Comment: I think you might have better luck getting an answer if you clarify the problem. I don't really understand what is happening. You said you found you need to use different size images for different browsers. You're doing that. And....?

Comment: Question updated, thank you very much

Comment: You are looking for bootstrap css.

Comment: Can bootstrap solve the problem?